# How to bypass admin's restrictions so I can have SU privileges?

Tags: permissions, sudo, password

I'm logged into my school's PC which is running Ubuntu 14.04.4. I can't access SU mode since the permissions are limited by the sysadmin.

I can't add myself as an admin, access the sudoers file or display the GRUB menu. I'm thinking about brute forcing the password but I'm pretty sure it will take like forever.

Is there a solution? Having to work on a Linux machine with limited permissions is so frustrating.

Comment: "brute forcing the password" is illegal in most countries unless you own the machine. Gaining access to a system you do not own in general is illegal too.

Answer (score 4):

All system administrators will have their good reasons to either allow or to restrict access on a computer they are responsible for.

This may be the case here. When you do not own a computer, and whenever you are not responsible for maintaining its operating system you should not try to forcibly gain access to this computer's system files. You may sooner or later break something by accident. Then it will be rather embarrassing to explain why this has happened.

Why not just **ask the administrator** to grant you the permissions you need?

If however you own that machine you will find good solutions here on this site on how to reset a lost administrator's password.